# About $ S $-free group and normal subgroup of $ S $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ S $ be a group. A group $ G $ is called $ S $-free if no quotient group of any subgroup of $ G $ is isomorphic to $ S $. Let $ G $ is finite group that is $ S $-free. if $ N \lhd S $, then is $ G $ a  $ N $-free group or no ?

Comment: Not necessarily. (You could have $N=1$ for example.)

Comment: If $ N $ be a normal minimal, then it is true ?

Comment: $G=N$ is another counterexample whenever $N < S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $N=\{1\}$ for a trivial counterexample. More generally, let $H_1$, $\ldots$, $H_n$ denote the isomorphism classes of quotients of subgroups of $G$. Take $N = H_i$ for some $i$, and take $K \ncong H_j$ for all $j$. With $S=K\times H_i$, $G$ is $S$-free but not $H_i$-free.

Comment: if $ G $ is a $ S_{4} $-group, then $ G $ is a $ B_{4} $-group ?

Comment: Let $G$ be a group and $K=H/N$ a quotient of a subgroup $H$ of $G$. If $U/M$ is a quotient of a subgroup of $K$, then $U/M \cong UN/MN$ is also a quotient of a subgroup of $G$. So, if $G$ is $S$-free, then any subquotient of $G$ is also $S$-free. In particular, if $G$ is $S_4$-free then it must be $B_4$-free, because $S_4$ is a quotient of $B_4$. (If that is what you are asking.) More directly, if you prefer, any epi. from a subgroup of $G$ to $B_4$ would give you one to $S_4$ by composition.

Comment: I should add: I interpreted $B_4$ to be the fourth braid group. If, as I infer from another question of yours, by $B_4$ you mean the Klein four normal subgroup of $S_4$, then my comment does not apply, but by answer does: A $S_4$-free group does not need to be $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$-free, obviously.